# Can a firefly control its glow?

Tags: entomology, bioluminescence, anecdotal-evidence

I've just seen this animation:

[image]

I always thought the firefly glow is ongoing slow chemical reaction, like in glowsticks though through different chemicals. As such it seems impossible to control quickly, like on this image.

Is this image real or edited? Can firefly control it's glow? If it can, how much?

Comment: Yes, fireflies control their glow patterns. Different species have different patterns. You can read about the luciferase reaction and its regulation [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luciferase).